# $\lim_{x \to +\infty} [\frac{e^{ax}(a\sin bx - b\cos bx)}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{e^{(1-a)x}}{(1-a)^2+b^2} ((1-a)\sin bx - b\cos bx)]$ where $0<a<1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[\frac{e^{ax}(a \sin bx-b \cos bx)}{a^2+b^2}-\frac{e^{(1-a)x}}{(1-a)^2+b^2} 
 ((1-a) \sin bx-b \cos bx)\right]$ where $0 < a < 1$. Prove that the given limit is not convergent for $a\neq \frac{1}{2}$.

**My try :**
For $a=\frac{1}{2}$ limit is $0$. For $a\neq \frac{1}{2}$ we have to prove that limit is not convergent

Comment: @Spectre any hints for the problem??

Comment: No idea bro ...

Comment: I am not as high-level as you are (I am 15 yrs), so I may take time to understand.

Comment: @Spectre no problem. Thanks for editing

Comment: You are welcome, sir ! :)

Comment: @Pj30 any hints for the problem?

Comment: Note the algebraic symmetry between $a$ and $(1-a)$.

Comment: The functions are 'dominated' by the $e^x$ terms and as $x\to\infty$, $e^x$ diverges to infinity because both $a$ and $1-a$ are non-negative. If they were negative, then the limit would go to $0$.

Comment: @C Squared then it is $\infty-\infty$

Comment: @Trebor how will the symmetry help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $1/2<a<1.$ Plug the sequence

$$x_n = (2\pi n) /b,\,\,n=1,2,\dots$$

into the expression. Another sequence to try is $y_n = (\pi/2 +2\pi n) /b.$

Comment: It is true for some values of x. Not for all values of x.?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "It is true for some values of x". Call this function $f.$ If you want to show the limit doesn't exist, all you need to do is find $x_n\to \infty$ and $y_n\to \infty$ along which $f$ has different behavior. For my choices of sequences, I'm getting $f(x_n)\to -\infty$ and $f(y_n)\to \infty.$ So no way can $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ exist.

Comment: Thank you so much.